# ¿LOAD FILE de CSV forzando que los campos vacíos sean nulos automáticamente?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Contexto:**
Tengo N ficheros .SQL, cada fichero .SQL contiene M líneas "LOAD FILE", el problema, es que hay columnas en ciertas tablas que pueden ser nulas y, a su vez, estas columnas (en algunos casos) son foreign keys

**Problema:**
A veces, los ficheros CSV contienen "" o "0" que en realidad deben cargarse como nulos.

**Intento de solución por mi parte:**
La única "solución" que veo posible es cargar los CSV, coger la primer línea con el objetivo de obtener los nombres de las columnas, usar los nombres de las columnas para agregarlos a la sentencia "LOAD FILE", reemplazar las columnas que son foreign keys por variables, ejemplo, (col1, col2, col3) por (@col1, col2, col3) donde @col1 es foreign key, entonces luego hago un SET col1 = ifnull(@col1, '');

**Problema con mi solución:**
No me funciona en todos los casos, además, agrega mucha complejidad.

**Pregunta:**
¿Existe alguna forma de indicarle al "LOAD FILE" que todo aquello que sea "" o "0" le asigne automáticamente un NULL?

*Ejemplo de código:*

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'micsv.csv' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'  ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@col1,col2,col3,col4,@col5,col6,col7,col8) SET col5= nullif(@col5, ''), SET col1 = nullif(@col1, '');
```